# Metrics server is currently unable to handle the request

Tags: kubernetes, hpa, metrics-server

I am new to kubernetes and was trying to apply horizontal pod autoscaling to my existing application. and after following other stackoverflow details - got to know that I need to install metric-server - and I was able to - but some how it's not working and unable to handle request.

- Further I followed few more things but unable to resolve the issue - I will really appreciate any help here.
  Please let me know for any further details you need for helping me :) Thanks in advance.

Steps followed:

kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml

```
serviceaccount/metrics-server created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:aggregated-metrics-reader created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server-auth-reader created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server created
service/metrics-server created
deployment.apps/metrics-server created
apiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io created
```

kubectl get deploy,svc -n kube-system | egrep metrics-server

```
deployment.apps/metrics-server   1/1     1            1           2m6s
service/metrics-server                       ClusterIP   10.32.0.32   <none>        443/TCP                        2m6s
```

kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep metrics-server

```
metrics-server-64cf6869bd-6gx88   1/1     Running   0          2m39s
```

vi ana_hpa.yaml

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: ana-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: common-services-auth
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 160
```

k apply -f ana_hpa.yaml

horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/ana-hpa created

k get hpa

```
NAME      REFERENCE                          TARGETS                         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
ana-hpa   StatefulSet/common-services-auth   <unknown>/160%, <unknown>/80%   1         10        0          4s
```

k describe hpa ana-hpa

```
Name:                                                     ana-hpa
Namespace:                                                default
Labels:                                                   <none>
Annotations:                                              <none>
CreationTimestamp:                                        Tue, 12 Apr 2022 17:01:25 +0530
Reference:                                                StatefulSet/common-services-auth
Metrics:                                                  ( current / target )
  resource memory on pods  (as a percentage of request):  <unknown> / 160%
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):     <unknown> / 80%
Min replicas:                                             1
Max replicas:                                             10
StatefulSet pods:                                         3 current / 0 desired
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason                   Message
  ----           ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: failed to get memory utilization: unable to get metrics for resource memory: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age                  From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----                 ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       38s (x8 over 2m23s)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  38s (x8 over 2m23s)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  invalid metrics (2 invalid out of 2), first error is: failed to get memory utilization: unable to get metrics for resource memory: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       23s (x9 over 2m23s)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get memory utilization: unable to get metrics for resource memory: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

kubectl edit deployments.apps -n kube-system metrics-server

Add hostNetwork: true

```
deployment.apps/metrics-server edited
```

kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep metrics-server

metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8-42hw9   1/1     Running   0          10m

k describe pod metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8-42hw9 -n kube-system

```
Name:                 metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8-42hw9
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 pusntyn196.apac.avaya.com/10.133.85.196
Start Time:           Tue, 12 Apr 2022 17:08:25 +0530
Labels:               k8s-app=metrics-server
                      pod-template-hash=5dc6dbdb8
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.133.85.196
IPs:
  IP:           10.133.85.196
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8
Containers:
  metrics-server:
    Container ID:  containerd://024afb1998dce4c0bd5f4e58f996068ea37982bd501b54fda2ef8d5c1098b4f4
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.1
    Image ID:      k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server@sha256:5ddc6458eb95f5c70bd13fdab90cbd7d6ad1066e5b528ad1dcb28b76c5fb2f00
    Port:          4443/TCP
    Host Port:     4443/TCP
    Args:
      --cert-dir=/tmp
      --secure-port=4443
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
      --kubelet-use-node-status-port
      --metric-resolution=15s
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 12 Apr 2022 17:08:26 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     200Mi
    Liveness:     http-get https://:https/livez delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get https://:https/readyz delay=20s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-g6p4g (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  tmp-dir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-g6p4g:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 2s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 2s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  2m31s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8-42hw9 to pusntyn196.apac.avaya.com
  Normal  Pulled     2m32s  kubelet            Container image "k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    2m31s  kubelet            Created container metrics-server
  Normal  Started    2m31s  kubelet            Started container metrics-server
```

kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep metrics-server

```
metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8-42hw9   1/1     Running   0          10m
```

kubectl logs -f metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8-42hw9 -n kube-system

```
E0412 11:43:54.684784       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:242] kube-system/extension-apiserver-authentication failed with : missing content for CA bundle "client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"
E0412 11:44:27.001010       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:242] key failed with : missing content for CA bundle "client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"

k logs -f metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8-42hw9 -n kube-system
    I0412 11:38:26.447305       1 serving.go:342] Generated self-signed cert (/tmp/apiserver.crt, /tmp/apiserver.key)
    I0412 11:38:26.899459       1 requestheader_controller.go:169] Starting RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
    I0412 11:38:26.899477       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
    I0412 11:38:26.899518       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:201] "Starting controller" name="client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"
    I0412 11:38:26.899545       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
    I0412 11:38:26.899546       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:201] "Starting controller" name="client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file"
    I0412 11:38:26.899567       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
    I0412 11:38:26.900480       1 dynamic_serving_content.go:131] "Starting controller" name="serving-cert::/tmp/apiserver.crt::/tmp/apiserver.key"
    I0412 11:38:26.900811       1 secure_serving.go:266] Serving securely on [::]:4443
    I0412 11:38:26.900854       1 tlsconfig.go:240] "Starting DynamicServingCertificateController"
    W0412 11:38:26.900965       1 shared_informer.go:372] The sharedIndexInformer has started, run more than once is not allowed
    I0412 11:38:26.999960       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
    I0412 11:38:26.999989       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
    I0412 11:38:26.999970       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
    E0412 11:38:27.000087       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:242] kube-system/extension-apiserver-authentication failed with : missing content for CA bundle "client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"
    E0412 11:38:27.000118       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:242] key failed with : missing content for CA bundle "client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"
```

kubectl top nodes

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

kubectl top pods

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Edit metrics server deployment yaml

```
Add - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

k apply -f metric-server-deployment.yaml

```
serviceaccount/metrics-server unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:aggregated-metrics-reader unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server-auth-reader unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server unchanged
service/metrics-server unchanged
deployment.apps/metrics-server configured
apiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io unchanged
```

kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep metrics-server

```
metrics-server-5dc6dbdb8-42hw9   1/1     Running   0          10m
```

kubectl top pods

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Also tried by adding below to metrics server deployment

```
    command:
    - /metrics-server
    - --kubelet-insecure-tls
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

Comment: Can you post the output of kubectl logs **AFTER** you added the insecure tls flag.

Comment: E0412 14:25:54.940679       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:242] kube-system/extension-apiserver-authentication failed with : missing content for CA bundle "client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"
E0412 14:26:27.247905       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:242] key failed with : missing content for CA bundle "client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file"

Answer (score 22):

First of all, execute the following command:

```
kubectl get apiservices
```

And checkout the availablity (status) of `kube-system/metrics-server` service.

- In case the availability is *True*:
  Add `hostNetwork: true` to the `spec` of your metrics-server deployment by executing the following command:

  ```bash
  kubectl edit deployment -n kube-system metrics-server
  ```

  It should look like the following:

  ```yaml
  ...
  spec:
    hostNetwork: true
  ...
  ```

  Setting hostNetwork to true means that Pod will have access to
  the host where it's running.
- In case the availability is *False (MissingEndpoints)*:

  1. Download metrics-server:

     ```
     wget https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.5.0/components.yaml
     ```
  2. Remove (legacy) metrics server:

     ```
     kubectl delete -f components.yaml
     ```
  3. Edit downloaded file and add `- --kubelet-insecure-tls` to args list:

     ```
     ...
     labels:
         k8s-app: metrics-server
     spec:
       containers:
       - args:
         - --cert-dir=/tmp
         - --secure-port=443
         - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
         - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
         - --metric-resolution=15s
         - --kubelet-insecure-tls # add this line
     ...
     ```
  4. Create service once again:

     ```
     kubectl apply -f components.yaml
     ```

Answer (score 11):

This can easily be resolved by editing the deployment yaml files and adding the `hostNetwork: true` after the `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst`

```
kubectl edit deployments.apps -n kube-system metrics-server
```

insert:

```
hostNetwork: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I have already added that as you can see the details above.

Comment: Should something else be executed after making this change? Or is it supposed to fix the issue automatically?

Comment: The issue fixed itself once I made the above change. Thx.

Comment: This resolves it for me also.  But I don't think it's the right fix

Comment: Opened a support ticket with Microsoft about this.

Comment: The issue in my case was an NSG rule blocking traffic. Once that deny rule was removed, everything started working fine. This step is no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help somebody for bare metal cluster:

```bash
$ helm --repo https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/metrics-server/ --kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/loc-cluster.config -n kube-system --set args='{--kubelet-insecure-tls}' upgrade --install metrics-server metrics-server
```

```bash
$ helm --kubeconfig=$HOME/.kube/loc-cluster.config -n kube-system uninstall metrics-server
```

Answer (score 1):

For me on EKS with helmfile I had to write in the `values.yaml` using the [metrics-server chart](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/tree/master/charts/metrics-server) :

```yaml
containerPort: 10250
```

The value was enforced by default to `4443` for an unknown reason when I first deployed the chart.

See doc:

- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/master/charts/metrics-server/values.yaml#L62
- [https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-metrics-server/#:~:text=confirm%20that%20your%20security%20groups](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-metrics-server/#:%7E:text=confirm%20that%20your%20security%20groups)

Then `kubectl top nodes` and `kubectl describe apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io` were working.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I deployed the `metrics-server` using the same command. Perhaps you can start fresh by removing existing resources and running:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

=======================================================================

It appears the `--kubelet-insecure-tls` flag was not configured correctly for the pod template in the deployment. The following should fix this:

1. Edit the *existing* deployment in the cluster with `kubectl edit deployment/metrics-server -nkube-system`.
2. Add the flag to the `spec.containers[].args` list, so that the deployment looks like this:

```
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=4443
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --metric-resolution=15s
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls      <=======ADD IT HERE.
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.1
...
```

3. Simply save your changes and let the deployment rollout the updated pods. You can use `watch -n1 kubectl get deployment/kube-metrics -nkube-system` and wait for `UP-TO-DATE` column to show `1`.

Like this:

```
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
metrics-server   1/1     1            1           16m
```

4. Verify with `kubectl top nodes`. It will show something like

```
NAME             CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
docker-desktop   222m         5%     1600Mi          41%
```

I've just verified this to work on a local setup. Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: --kubelet-insecure-tls is indeed not configured as a default because on most setup it's a bad idea from my understanding. And above of that this step was already done in the initail question adding it to command or args should not make any difference if i am correct.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a bad idea to disable TLS :) I wanted to reiterate the solution because I believe the parameter didn't get configured correctly. And since the authentication issue persisted, it lead me to believe that the issue is with TLS indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Please configuration aggregation layer correctly and carefully, you can use this link for help : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-aggregation-layer/.

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  name: <name of the registration object>
spec:
  group: <API group name this extension apiserver hosts>
  version: <API version this extension apiserver hosts>
  groupPriorityMinimum: <priority this APIService for this group, see API documentation>
  versionPriority: <prioritizes ordering of this version within a group, see API documentation>
  service:
    namespace: <namespace of the extension apiserver service>
    name: <name of the extension apiserver service>
  caBundle: <pem encoded ca cert that signs the server cert used by the webhook>
```

It would be helpful to provide `kubectl version` return value.

Answer (score 0):

For us on a Google Cloud GKE **private** cluster we had to add a firewall rule to allow for this traffic.

The use case here is a "Aggregated API server" and the process on how to add the correct firewall rule is described in the [private cluster docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#add_firewall_rules).

For us we had to allow the port `6443` from the failure message inside `kubectl describe apiservice v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io`:

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-03-07T11:17:17Z
    Message:               failing or missing response from https://10.4.1.14:6443 [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was occurring on my local k3s cluster and found out that restarting the k3s service resolves it after 5 to 10 minutes.

```
sudo systemctl restart k3s
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked in AWS EKS. I've had the same problem after instalation Helm Chart.
Problem was in misconfiguration of the namespace and port in my deployment and v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io

I ran this command to check it:

```
# kubectl describe deployment metrics-server -n <Your namespace>

# kubectl describe apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io

# kubectl edit deployment metrics-server -n "Your namespace"

# kubectl edit apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
```

After i set it up to 4443 and same "namespace"
I checked with command:

```
# kubectl top nodes
```

and got positive result.
Here is the link for guys who worked with AWS as well:
[enter link description here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-metrics-server#:%7E:text=confirm%20that%20your%20security%20groups)